# Change BitLocker Pin with Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, bitlocker

I work in the IT department of our organization. When a remote employee leaves the company we would like our automation tool (K1000) to push a batch file command to force change the BitLocker pin and reboot the computer. I wrote a batch file to change the PIN. It goes as far in command prompt to request a new pin but I can't get the batch to actually to accept the password.
In the below example, it just stays waiting for user input, any thoughts?

I'm hoping to use this for Windows 7 and 10.

```
@echo off

 call :isAdmin

 if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    goto :run
 ) else (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto :UACPrompt
 )

 exit /b

 :isAdmin
    fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% >nul
 exit /b

 :run
manage-bde -changepin c:
%SendKeys% "helloworld{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "helloworld{ENTER}"

 exit /b

 :UACPrompt
   echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %~1", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

   "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
  exit /B
```

Comment: Batch files do not have any native sendkeys method so I have no idea what you have assigned to that variable or how you are expecting to do keyboard input.

Comment: Also if you are trying to use Vbscript or Jscript to send keystrokes to the Window, you would need to spawn manage-bde into another process.  Batch files are interpreted line by line. It will never do the SendKeys process until the manage-bde process has completed.